# Use conditional for Element API results?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Using the Element API is there a way to get entries by `dateUpdated` OR `dateCreated` within the last whatever time, say day?

Or a way to get the entry IDs for both of those criteria then do a query based on just the IDs from both results?

I want to get any entry that was created or updated within the last day using the API but can't quite get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the latest of both, unless I'm missing something, you should just be able to query on `dateUpdated`.

When you create an entry the first time, its `dateUpdated` gets set to the same date as the `dateCreated`... So if you query your entries on `dateUpdated` only, you will get all entries created + updated in your time frame I guess.

As far as code goes, this should do it:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'entries.json' => function() {
            $timeframe = (new \DateTime('1 day ago'))->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
            return [
                'elementType' => Entry::class,
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'entries',
                    'dateUpdated' => '>=' . $timeframe,
                ],
                'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                    return [
                        'title' => $entry->title,
                        'url' => $entry->url,
                    ];
                },
            ];
        },
    ]
];
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that. That will probably work fine for my situation then.